# Detect SD card using WMI Query

Tags: c#, invoke, wmi-query

I have a query that return USB devices attached in:

```
   SelectQuery sq = new SelectQuery("select DeviceID, Model from Win32_DiskDrive where   InterfaceType='USB'");
   ManagementObjectCollection MOC = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sq).Get();
```

But it doesn't retrieve the SD card information.

How do i can retrieve this SD cards information using WMI queries?

Comment: what does it return then..? [Almost Everything in WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18268/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-Hardw)

Comment: O sorry, i modified "select DeviceID, Model from Win32_DiskDrive where   InterfaceType='USB'" removing "where   InterfaceType='USB" XD sorry .

Answer (score 0):

i modified "select DeviceID, Model from Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType='USB'" removing "where InterfaceType='USB"